# Unity can't refer to GameManager script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

[image]
[image]

Hi, can someone help me with my script? I can't refer to my GameManager script. GameManager script is not private, Test() function is not private, file name and class name of GameManager are the exact same. So what's the problem here? (Yes I did try to assign it in the inspector)

I tried to refer to the GameManager script first by calling the Test() function in GameManager, which logs a string, but that doesn't work.

Comment: [**Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)

Comment: Sounds like you either didn't assign any `GameManager` to the `gameMangerScript` slot in the Inspector or it was destroyed in the meantime ?

Comment: I did assign the GameManager to the GameManager script and it does not get destroyed in any kind of way.

Comment: Ok, I solved it. I had to make the GameManager to a prefab apparently because my Bullet script is assigned to a prefab. Ty anyways

Comment: c# doesn't just invent exceptions ;) What you get is not a compiler error but a runtime exception telling you `gameMangerScript` is `null` the moment you try to access it ... how it reached that state is up to you to investigate ... for instance check if the Inspector you are looking at is indeed of the instance throwing this exception. You could add a `Debug.Log(name, this);` and check if a) the log appears multiple times, b) the name is of the expected object and C) clicking on it once highlights the expected object

Comment: `Ok, I solved it.` => This will **not** solve your problem but rather introduce others! Now your `GameManager` will be prefab and unrelated to your scene => it itself can not have any scene references either ... most probably not desired. You rather want to "inject" your `GameManager` reference the moment you spawn (instantiate) your bullets like e.g. `var bullet = Intantiate(bullerPrefab); bullet.gameManagerScript = gameManager;` .. and then whoever is creating those bullets needs to get the `GameManager` reference the usual way via the Inspector as well